# upload file to Google drive through html form and store url in input-text box to write to mysql?

Tags: php, google-drive-api, google-api-php-client

how to upload a file through the html form either by file upload or Google file picker and storing the fil url to mysql database ?

i tried to upload file through file upload and passing it to the $file variable in the below code, the file is uploading but is invalid in the Google drive ?

```
    <?php
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/Google_Client.php';
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_DriveService.php';

$myfile=$_REQUEST['file'];

$type=mime_content_type($myfile);

$client = new Google_Client();
// Get your credentials from the APIs Console
$client->setClientId('');
$client->setClientSecret('');
$client->setRedirectUri('');
$client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'));

$service = new Google_DriveService($client);

$authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();

//Request authorization
print "Please visit:\n$authUrl\n\n";
print "Please enter the auth code:\n";
$authCode = trim(fgets(STDIN));

// Exchange authorization code for access token
$accessToken = $client->authenticate($authCode);
$client->setAccessToken($accessToken);

//Insert a file
$file = new Google_DriveFile();
$file->setTitle('My New document');
$file->setDescription('A test document');
$file->setMimeType($type);

$data = file_get_contents($myfile);

$createdFile = $service->files->insert($file, array(
      'data' => $data,
      'mimeType' => $type,
    ));

print_r($createdFile);

?>
```

Answer (score 3):

use `$myfile=$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];` instead of `$myfile=$_REQUEST['file'];`

You use 'trim(fgets(STDIN));' this won't work from a html page.

Your app have to read your authcode from `$_GET['code']` when google redirect the authorized user back to your site.

You can test this with the code shown below. To test it you have to save the code as `index.php` and make it available on `http://localhost/`.
`setRedirectUri` only allow to redirect to a main domain (`http://localhost/test.php` is not allowed).
When `$_GET['code']` is empty you will be redirected to accounts.google.com. 
After you grant the app you will be send back to `http://localhost/?code={your authcode}`.
Now you can save the authcode to use it on other pages too.

In this test code the file upload form will submit to  `http://localhost/?code={your authcode}` cause the action attribute is empty.

`print_r($createdFile);` will give you the information to store the file url in your database.

Don't forget setup up an Google API console project to get your credentials first, see also http://enarion.net/programming/php/google-client-api/google-client-api-php/

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/Google_Client.php';
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_DriveService.php';
$client = new Google_Client();
// Get your credentials from the APIs Console
$client->setClientId('**********.apps.googleusercontent.com');
$client->setClientSecret('********************');
$client->setRedirectUri('http://localhost/');
$client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'));

if(empty($_GET['code']))
{
    $client->authenticate();
}
?>
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="">
<input type="file" name="file">
<input type="submit" value="verzenden">
</form>
<?


if(!empty($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']))
{

$myfile=$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

$type=mime_content_type($myfile);



$service = new Google_DriveService($client);

// Exchange authorization code for access token
$accessToken = $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
$client->setAccessToken($accessToken);

//Insert a file
$file = new Google_DriveFile();
$file->setTitle('My New document');
$file->setDescription('A test document');
$file->setMimeType($type);

$data = file_get_contents($myfile);

$createdFile = $service->files->insert($file, array(
      'data' => $data,
      'mimeType' => $type,
    ));

print_r($createdFile);
}
```

Comment: still the file uploaded is invalid ?

Comment: what is the ouput of `print_r($createdFile)`?